# Button inside Update Panel is not triggered, in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE_EditGroup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="btnCancel" />
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lst_allmembers" DataValueField="FirstName" runat="server" />                       
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" /><asp:ListBox ID="lst_grpmembers" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_remove" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /></asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The add button has a event OnClick="btn_Add_Click"

```
  protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        lst_grpmembers.Items.Add(lst_allmembers.SelectedItem.Text);
             }
```

The event is not triggered and when I click the add button nothing happens. And the Update Button was working fine before I added the update panel now only the cancel button closes the popup no other button works inside the pop up
How to trigger the event.

Comment: In your script manager add this: `asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"` that way we get more information about the error

Comment: Also set a break point at btn_Add_Click and see if it even gets triggered.  My thinking is this error is not specific enough to find a root cause.  set EnablePartialRendering to false to get more details.

Comment: It is executed. after i added <Triggers> <asp:Asy.. but the popup closes and gives an error  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.

Comment: Do you have validation somewhere? Have you tried setting `CausesValidation="true"` to test whether validation is the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the UpdatePanel's `ChildrenAsTriggers` property to `true`.  This will cause any postbacks triggered by the UpdatePanel's child elements to update its content.

**EDIT**: Just realized that `btn_Add` is a nested control, so you will have to explicitly call it out as an `UpdatePanel Trigger`.  Add the following to your UpdatePanel markup, after the ContentTemplate:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Add" /> 
</Triggers>
```

**EDIT #2**: To keep your modal popup from closing when an async postback occurs, move the `UpdatePanel` inside the panel specified by ModalPopupExtender's PopupControlID:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lst_allmembers" DataValueField="FirstName" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" />
            <asp:ListBox ID="lst_grpmembers" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btn_remove" runat="server" Text="Remove" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
             <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.  Should I add <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate_Click" />   for click as well

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that the issue is caused by having the ModalPopupExtender's Cancel button within an UpdatePanel.  Can you remove `CancelControlID="btnCancel"` from your ModalPopupExtender and see if the error persists?

Comment: It works but when I click add it add the selected item to the 2nd list box and closes the pop up and when I again open it the item add remains and every time I click add the popup closes when I reopen the values is still there

Comment: Ok, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: After i add items to the list using the add button I have to click update button, but the popup closes immediately after i click add button. I want the pop up to be open even after I click add button

Comment: Please see Edit #2 in my answer.