# How to remove a "row" of controls dynamically created inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where I need to remove a whole row(it's not a table, I just call it a row to give a better description) of controls dynamically created.
I didn't have any problem creating the controls , but now it turns up that the events for the buttons do not work

Here is the code for the aspx page (Default.aspx):

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblContador" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="SI( " />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSi" runat="server" Width="400"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text=": " />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtValorVSi" runat="server" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text=" )" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAgregar" runat="server" Text="+ Añadir" OnClick="btnAgregar_Click" />
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text="SINO ( " />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSino" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal5" runat="server" Text=" )" />
                <br />
                <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the code behind page (Default.aspx.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static List<TextBox> arregloTxtCondicion = new List<TextBox>();
        static List<TextBox> arregloTxtValorVSiPeroSi = new List<TextBox>();
        static List<Button> arregloBtnEliminar = new List<Button>();
        static int contadorControles;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                contadorControles = 0;
                lblContador.Text = "";
                contadorControles = 0;
            }
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < contadorControles; i++)
                    AgregarControles(arregloTxtCondicion[i], arregloTxtValorVSiPeroSi[i], arregloBtnEliminar[i]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblContador.Text = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        protected void AgregarControles(TextBox txtCondicion, TextBox txtValorV, Button btnEliminar)
        {
            try
            {
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" PERO.SI( "));
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(txtCondicion);
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" : "));
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(txtValorV);
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(" ) "));
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(btnEliminar);
                pnlMain.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblContador.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int numeroRegistro = contadorControles;

                //creamos nuestros controles
                TextBox txtCondicion = new TextBox();
                txtCondicion.ID = "txtPeroSi" + numeroRegistro.ToString();
                txtCondicion.Width = 400;
                arregloTxtCondicion.Add(txtCondicion);

                TextBox txtValorV = new TextBox();
                txtValorV.ID = "txtPeroSiValorV" + numeroRegistro.ToString();
                txtValorV.Width = 100;
                arregloTxtValorVSiPeroSi.Add(txtValorV);

                Button btnEliminar = new Button();
                btnEliminar.ID = "btnEliminar" + numeroRegistro.ToString();
                btnEliminar.Text = "- Quitar";
                btnEliminar.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEliminar_Click);
                arregloBtnEliminar.Add(btnEliminar);

                //agregamos los Controles al Panel
                AgregarControles(txtCondicion, txtValorV, btnEliminar);
                contadorControles++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblContador.Text = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        protected void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMensaje.Text = "Se elimino elemento: " + sender.ToString();
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650592/button-inside-update-panel-is-not-triggered-in-asp-net

        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks my page 
[image]
And I need that when I press a "- Quitar"("remove" in English) button , all the controls in that row are removed.
Have you ever done something similar??? Do you have any idea what's going wrong??

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd highly suggest using a GridView for this.  I don't see it in your markup.

Comment: Use a gridview. Then you can customize your controls using template fields.

Answer (score 0):

Put each row in a different asp:Panel  and then on button click you can remove it like this.

((Button)sender).Parent.Controls.Remove;

Something like this may works for you.

Comment: but how can I later retrieve the data from the textboxes??

Comment: Same way you are getting now.

Comment: haha that's exactly why I'm thinking of trying with a grid, because I don't know in which "row" I'm in :S

Comment: Yes using Grid is a better option. But if  you want to go with this method then you can get the data like this: foreach(Control c in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>()) {  string text1 = ((TextBox)c.FindControl("textboxid")).Text; }

Comment: The above code will loop through each of the row and will get the values from it.