# Button click not working inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, button, triggers, updatepanel

When I use Button inside Update panel it doesnot fire click event but outside the update panel it works.

here is the code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnBlock" class="Button" Text="BlockCalls" runat="server"       
            onclick="btnBlock_Click" Enabled="True" Width="100px" />  
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnBlock" /> 
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code for button is

```
protected void btnBlock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    CtiWS.CtiWS CtiWS1 = new CtiWS.CtiWS();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('"+Convert.ToString(Session["BlockCalls"])+"')</script>");
    if (btnBlock.Text == "BlockCalls")
    {
        btnBlock.Text = "UnBlockCalls";
        CtiWS1.BlockCalls("", "", HttpContext.Current.Session["HOSTID"].ToString()); //server block calls
    }
    else
    {
        btnBlock.Text = "BlockCalls";
        CtiWS1.BlockCalls("", "", HttpContext.Current.Session["HOSTID"].ToString()); //server unblock calls 
    }

}
```

Comment: you just need to give postback trigger instead of asychrinous postback

Comment: I dont want page to refresh after Button is clicked.
when I use postback trigger it refreshes the page

Comment: just seen this link.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650592/button-inside-update-panel-is-not-triggered-in-asp-net @user3713775

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

set `ChildrenAsTriggers` to `true` and add `EventName="Click"` in `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
                ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
   <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnBlock" class="Button" Text="BlockCalls" runat="server"       
                 onclick="btnBlock_Click" Enabled="True" Width="100px" />  
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnBlock" EventName="Click"/> 
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for the button? It's in the Update Panel - ChildrenAsTriggers is true - you don't need it.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse because the ChildrenAsTriggers is a full postback trigger request. If you want to do an Async trigger, you need to be specific