# Asp.net button onclick event is not firing serverside code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This has been discussed too many times already, but none of those threads helped me.

**Below is .aspx code.**

```
<div id="Panel_login" runat="server" class="panel-default">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_login"  UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtb_loginEmailRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txtb_loginEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email can't be Empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtb_loginEmail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" runat="server" TextMode="Email" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtb_loginPasswordRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txtb_loginPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password can't be Empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                        
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtb_loginPassword" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:Button ID="btn_userlogin" runat="server" OnClick="loginUser" Text="Login" />                             
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

**Below is my .cs file code.**

```
 protected void loginUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
     log.Debug("login_user is called");    
 }
```

On click of button, it should fire event, but it is not happening.

I have tried adding triggers to Update Panel for this button click, still didnt work.

**It only gets fired when another button on same page is fired previously.**

Can someone suggests what I am missing here.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I guess that your `Page_Load` misses a `!IsPostBack` check. Show it

Comment: I have nothing in Page_Load(), It shouldn't matter. it works for another button which i have on page.

Comment: How do you know "it is not happening"? By redirect not happening, or by debugging through the code?

Comment: Add `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` to UpdatePanel

Comment: I have tried putting log.Debug("login_user is called"); as first statement.

Comment: @Div. tried that too., adding triggers to update panel. didnt work

Comment: Is email or password empty?

Comment: @DKR, Did you tried to add `AsyncPostBackTrigger`?

Comment: @selami no. asp.net validators make sure of that.

Comment: @Div Yes. I did try that

Comment: @DKR, OK, Can you add this in the question, how did you try.

Comment: Just asking Why `UpdateMode="Conditional"` instead of you can use `UpdateMode="Always"`

Comment: @JaydipJ.. thats just for future reference. I would need to add more controls in same div which I would like to update manually. However this shouldnt be the cause of issue.

Comment: for debugging purpose, take button out of the update panel and try

Comment: also refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075538/button-click-not-working-inside-update-panel

Comment: @Ramakrishnan I have already tried adding triggers to update panel... not working.

Comment: @DKR - its weired, i tried with your code, it triggers the server code

Comment: @All ... This is weird. It only gets fired when another button on same page is clicked previously.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the event never getting wired up. Try...

(1) In design mode delete the button, drag a new one back on the design surface, then rename your button. OR

(2) Go into design view, click the button, then properties, look at the Lightening Bolt Icon (event) remove that event, save, and add it back and save.

Comment: .I have tried that already. didnt work. I am not new to asp.net :) Thanks though :)