# How can I get UpdatePanel to work for multiple buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, updatepanel, page-refresh

I have an application that has multiple buttons. I am trying to keep the page from being reloaded (which interferes with other Controls) every time the button is clicked, so I have wrapped the main part of the code in `<asp:UpdatePanel><ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>`. I have already looked at multiple solutions for single buttons involving the use `<Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>...` just after the `</ContentTemplate>` but this does not resolve my issue. I am using `AjaxControlToolkit` (I have added `using AjaxControlToolkit;` to my C# file) as well as a `ModalPopExtender` which seem to affect the behavior of `UpdatePanel`, according to some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650592/button-inside-update-panel-is-not-triggered-in-asp-net?answertab=active#tab-top). Without posting the entire applications (its very long), here is the basic layout of the current code (aspx and C#) and what I have tried so far. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="container" id="table_controls_section" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%;">
            <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
                <table style="border-style:solid; border-color: darkblue; border-width:thin; border-bottom-width: 0px; width:100%;">                     
                    <tr>
                      <th style="text-align: center;">Requestor Info</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                        <asp:Button ID="uxTicketHistoryButton" runat="server" Text="Show Ticket History"  style="color: blue;" OnClick="uxTicketHistoryButton_Click"/>&nbsp;
                         <asp:Button ID="uxUseContactInfoButton" runat="server" Text="Use Contact Info" style="color: blue;" OnClick="uxUseContactInfoButton_Click" />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxUseContactInfoButton" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxTicketHistoryButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
namespace BCA_TicketManagement
{
    public partial class Summary : Page
    {
       ....
      protected void uxTicketHistoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { ....
      }
      protected void uxUseContactInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { ....
      }
    }
}
```

**Things I have tried so far:**
1) Adding `using AjaxControlToolkit;` to C# code. It shows in my References as well.
2) Adding `UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` to my `asp:UpdatePanel`. Also tried changing `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`. No difference.
3) Trying to get `UpdatePanel` to work for a single button by adding `<Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger...>` using the `ControlID` for that button. No change.
4) Adding `xmlns:asp="#unknown"` to `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger...>`. Throws error `AsyncPostBackTrigger has no property 'xmlns:asp="#unknown"'`
**Note** This page is loaded inside a `<form>` tag in the `Master.site`using `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide your `EventName` to your Trigger as shown in the following example:

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxUseContactInfoButton" EventName="Click" />
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxTicketHistoryButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

I hope that will resolve your problem.

Comment: This looked promising. I added the `EventName="Click"` but it is still reloading the page everytime I click the buttons.

Comment: Which content of Page you're updating? Is it in your `UpdatePanel` or outside the `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: The content itself (including the buttons) are inside the `UpdatePanel` (as shown above). Is that not correct?

Comment: I am not seeing any area which you're updating in your code. You must wrap all the code and it'll not refresh your page, but will update the area of UpdatePanel ContentTemplate.

Comment: Right, I didn't post the entire app in the example because its so long, but essentially everything is wrapped in  `<asp:UpdatePanel...><ContentTemplate> ... code here...</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>`, so I am not sure why its not working.

Comment: Try removing `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` property from your `UpdatePanel` and in your `ScriptManager` add a property `EnablePartialRendering="true"`.

Comment: **Update**: So, I now believe that UpdatePanel is working correctly. There were 2 things which were fooling me: 1) I was using `jQuery` to select rows in a Gridview (not shown) the selected row disappeared whenever I clicked a button and 2) I have a tab area. The default was the tab1 area. If I clicked tab 2 and then clicked a button, it reverted back to the default; tab1. But everything else on the page stayed (so the entire page isn't reloading, but certain elements are defaulting or breaking). I'll post a follow up question.